# Google street view multiple arrow marks issue between panorama

Tags: google-street-view, google-streetview-publish

In google street view API after publishing all panorama images with latitude and longitude, heading and connections nearly after 2-3 hours initially arrow marks connections comes perfectly..but after approximately 24 hours extra links(arrow marks) are getting added between panorama images..how to solve this..?

I have tried with different scenarios like...i have three panorama 1,2,3
scenario:1
connections [1-->2 , 2-->1, 2-->3 , 3-->2]
scenario:2
connections [1-->2 , 2-->3]
but my problem still exists...

**strong text**
when i send my request initially -
     '{"1":{"pose":{"latitude":"12.912440944324","longitude":"77.585632559827"},"heading":"4.45","connections":[2,3]},"2":{"pose":{"latitude":"12.912425081018","longitude":"77.58564121332"},"heading":"0","connections":1},"3":{"pose":{"latitude":"12.912453965825","longitude":"77.58561986013"},"heading":"2.15","connections":[1,4]},"4":{"pose":{"latitude":"12.912466987325","longitude":"77.585607160431"},"heading":"0","connections":[3,5]},"5":{"pose":{"latitude":"12.912480008826","longitude":"77.585594460732"},"heading":"0","connections":[4,6]},"6":{"pose":{"latitude":"12.912492712923","longitude":"77.585607494417"},"heading":"5.53","connections":[5,7]},"7":{"pose":{"latitude":"12.912505417019","longitude":"77.585620528104"},"heading":"9.8","connections":[6,8]},"8":{"pose":{"latitude":"12.912490918923","longitude":"77.585631414393"},"heading":"11.3","connections":[7,9]},"9":{"pose":{"latitude":"12.912476420827","longitude":"77.585642300682"},"heading":"10.93","connections":8},"10":{"pose":{"latitude":"12.912429059007","longitude":"77.585584619159"},"heading":"0","connections":11}    } '   when i receive request from google street view API after nearly 24 hours

'{"1":{"pose":{"latitude":12.912440944324,"longitude":77.585632559827},"heading":4.449999809265137,"connections":[2,3]},"2":{"pose":{"latitude":12.912425081018,"longitude":77.58564121332},"connections":1},"3":{"pose":{"latitude":12.912453965825,"longitude":77.58561986013},"heading":2.1500000953674316,"connections":[1,4,2,8]},"4":{"pose":{"latitude":12.912466987325,"longitude":77.585607160431},"connections":[3,5,6,8]},"5":{"pose":{"latitude":12.912480008826,"longitude":77.585594460732},"connections":[4,6]},"6":{"pose":{"latitude":12.912492712923,"longitude":77.585607494417},"heading":5.53000020980835,"connections":[5,7,3,4,8]},"7":{"pose":{"latitude":12.912505417019,"longitude":77.585620528104},"heading":9.800000190734863,"connections":[6,8]},"8":{"pose":{"latitude":12.912490918923,"longitude":77.585631414393},"heading":11.300000190734863,"connections":[7,9,3,4]},"9":{"pose":{"latitude":12.912476420827,"longitude":77.585642300682},"heading":10.930000305175781,"connections":8}    }'

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the [Street View App](https://www.google.com/streetview/apps/) with your account and disable "Auto-connect 360 photos" in the settings. You may need to re-upload your connections to get rid of the automatically created connections.

Comment: I am actually not using street view app.....using street view API i have developed my own code..is there anything extra i can do??

Comment: I understand what you are doing, but this setting influences the API usage, and this setting is not available in the API.

Comment: can u just provide me any reference link??

Comment: I noticed this since the early API days, and it was confirmed by a Google engineer at the Street View Summit in San Francisco.

Comment: so can u just guide me how to solve this now??what steps or measures i should fallow??

Comment: Please have a look at the original answer! Download the App, change the setting, re-upload the connections.

Comment: hi...i have tried to publish some images by turning off auto connect from street view app..still problem persists...what i should do?

Comment: how can i turn off auto connect of user programatically??

Comment: @Veeresh Can you please accept my answer to your original question? Thank you.

Comment: It looks like this is a known issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124355976

Comment: there is no updates for this issue yet...so how can i manage it??